# Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources"

Tags: contract-development, truffle, nft, ganache, truffle-migration

I'm following this tutorial on creating my own nft and I came across this problem. Can someone help me PS C:\Users\caclc\contracts> truffle migrate

## Compiling your contracts...

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'ganache'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)

## 1_initial_migration.js

```
C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\459.bundled.js:27188
        throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources");
        ^

Error: Could not find artifacts for HelloBlockchain from any sources
    at Resolver.require (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\resolver\dist\lib\resolver.js:60:1)     
    at Object.require (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:172:1)
    at ResolverIntercept.require (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\ResolverIntercept.js:22:1)
    at C:\Users\caclc\contracts\migrations\1_initial_migration.js:1:30
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:139:12)
    at Script.runInNewContext (node:vm:144:17)
    at Object.file (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\require\require.js:94:1)
    at Migration._load (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:44:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Migration.run (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:217:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:110:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:87:1)
    at runMigrations (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate\run.js:76:1)     
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate\run.js:44:1)
    at Command.run (C:\Users\caclc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.4.29 (core: 5.4.29)
Node v16.15.1
```

Comment: Please include your code or the tutorial link.

Comment: Preferably the code because external links can be taken down which makes this question worth less to the community.